# Filtering in excel by last two characters that are alphanumeric

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a large spread sheet of warehouse locations that I need to sort by the last two digits and I need to filter on the ones that are alpha numeric. Below is the example of what i'm looking at. I need everything that doesn't end with the characters D1,D2,D3 and D4

```
LOCID
1350010C3
1350010D1
1350010D4
1350011A3
1350011B1
1350011C1
1350011C2
1350011C4
1350011D1
1350011D3
1350011D5
1350012D5
1350013A4
```

Comment: create another column that has the last two characters, then use that column to do your sort and your filter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column to your spreadsheet with just the last two characters of `LOCID`.

For example, with the `LOCID` in cell `A2`, a formula to get the last two characters would be `=RIGHT(A2,2)`.

Sort your spreadsheet on the new column.